# Will Deleting An FCM Token Also Unsubscribe It From An FCM Topic?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I generate an FCM token in the browser I also send it to my server, which subscribes it to a topic with the firebase admin module like so:

`messaging.subscribeToTopic(token, 'all')`

I'm wondering if I delete the token in the browser using the `messaging.deleteToken(currentToken)` method do I also need to unsubscribe that same token using `messaging.unsubscribeFromTopic(token, 'all');` on my server or does firebase do that automatically when the token is delete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A topic subscription is really just a simple way to subscribe many ID tokens to a string. On the FCM fan-out servers that is pretty much exactly what is stored: a list of tokens associated with each topic.

Deleting a token will not really unsubscribe the token from the topic. But since the token is the only way that FCM can deliver messages to a device, messages sent to any topics the token was subscribed to can no longer be delivered (and will be cleaned up behind the scenes automatically).

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, when you say "cleaned up behind the scenes automatically" I'm thinking that if the message can't be delivered via the topic because the token has been deleted then the token will be removed automatically from the topic. Is that what you're implying?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact implementation, but know that expired tokens are purged from the fan-out server. I could imagine it'd be something like [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L74-L87), but haven't checked (nor needed to check) the actual implementation.